# Converting years to days, hours, minutes C#

Tags: c#

I am having difficulty converting my captured string to a double datatypes I think I am somewhat on the right track but some guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
        //Capture the users name
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Please enter you name: ");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();

        //Capture the year in decimal datatype
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks" +userName+ "Now Please enter you age:");
        string userAge = Console.ReadLine();

        double userYear = double.Parse(userAge);

        double userDays = 365 * userYear;

        double userHours = 24 * userDays;

        double userSeconds = 86400 * userHours;
```

Comment: for input userAge = 10.5 i got output (after debugging) as UserDays: 3832.5 Users Hours: 91980 UserSeconds: 7947072000.. Code has no problem. Is there any specific string for which you are not getting desired output?

Comment: Keep in mind that a year is not always 365 days. Will your program need to include "Leap Years", etc.?  C# has date functions to help with this, if you need them.

Comment: Your title and question don't really match. You're asking about converting years to days, etc., in the title, but in your question you talk about having difficult with converting strings to doubles. There's going to be a problem if someone enters "Old enough to know better. Not old enough to care." as their age, but that should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly fine for me in LINQPad:

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Use the Double class, not the primary datatype double.

```
double number = double.Parse("1"); //don´t works, because double is a primary data type

double number = Double.Parse("1"); //works
```

Comment: "don´t works" --- could you please elaborate what exactly "does not work" in the `double.Parse("1")` expression?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between `double` and `Double`.  `double` is a synonym for `System.Double`.

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen! Got it figured out!